# Return total fields count in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to retrieve the total fields count with respect to fields name in a single query from a collection?

I am expecting a result like this

```
{
  "field_1":101,
  "field_2":93,
  "field_3":1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$project` convert root object to array using `$objectToArray`, this will create k(key) and v(value) structure of array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$group` by k(key) and get `total` fields count using `$sum`
- `$group` by null and construct an array with k(key) and v(value) fields format
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object after converting from array using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { root: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$root.k",
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: {
        $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$total" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$root"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/80JSGraQuCT)

Answer (score 1):

Yes

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZGdoGmBB4nE)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    field_2: {
      $push: {
        $cond: [
          "$field_2",
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    field_1: {
      $push: {
        $cond: [
          "$field_1",
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
   _id:0,
    field_1: {
      $sum: "$field_1"
    },
    field_2: {
      $sum: "$field_2"
    }
  }
})
```

[Be aware](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html):

> When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null